# Text Input very slow in WPF Application

Tags: wpf

I have a simple WPF application in which I open a webcam and set it to 30 Frames per second, like this:

```
 webcam = new WebCamCapture();
 webcam.FrameNumber = ((ulong)(0ul));
 webcam.TimeToCapture_milliseconds = FrameNumber;
 webcam.ImageCaptured += new WebCamCapture.WebCamEventHandler(webcam_ImageCaptured);
```

This application shows the camera preview in an ImageControl (30 frames per second).

Below the Image box, I've a TextBox

```
<TextBox Name="txtMsg" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="214" Height="22" Margin="0,260,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBox>
```

Now when I try to type in the textbox, it takes seconds to reply. Sometimes I press keys several times, but get no response. If I delay the camera capture event (e.g. 1 frame per second) it works fine.

My question is how can I have the UI updated frequently, but get a fast response in TextBox at the same time.

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you initialize the webcam, in constructor of App? What does an event handler? What about webcam resolution, is it a way to reduce it?

Answer (score 1):

The webcam object is running in the `UI Thread`. Here is an example, how you can start it in a separate `Thread`. Be careful, because the `ImageCaptured` event is fired in a background `Thread`, so you have to call a `Dispatcher`.

```
private void _StartWebCam()
{
    ThreadStart webCamThreadStart = () =>
    {
        webcam = new WebCamCapture();
        webcam.FrameNumber = ((ulong)(0ul));
        webcam.TimeToCapture_milliseconds = FrameNumber;
        webcam.ImageCaptured += new WebCamCapture.WebCamEventHandler(webcam_ImageCaptured);
    };
    Thread threadnameThread = new Thread(webCamThreadStart) { IsBackground = true };
    threadnameThread.Start();
}

private void webcam_ImageCaptured(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
    {
        //Set you captured Image to your ImageControl
    }));
}
```

Comment: Thanx a lot for your help. The input text blocking issue is resolved now, but the event webcam_ImageCaptured never get fired now? Can you please put a light on that.

Thanks.

Comment: the event webcam_ImageCaptured never get fired now? Can you please put a light on that. Thanks

Comment: Without some more informations, I can't help you. Post some more code about the `WebCamCapture` class. You have to put your "webcam take image" logic in a separate `Thread` and there in a `while loop`.