# How to raise a UI event from a background Thread

Tags: wpf

I've a WebCamCapture class that inherits from UserControl class and I start it in a separate thread like this

```
    ThreadStart webCamThreadStart = () =>
    {
        webcam = new WebCamCapture();

        webcam.FrameNumber = ((ulong)(0ul));
        webcam.TimeToCapture_milliseconds = FrameNumber;

        webcam.ImageCaptured += new WebCamCapture.WebCamEventHandler(webcam_ImageCaptured);

        Start();
    };



    Thread threadnameThread = new Thread(webCamThreadStart) { IsBackground = true };
    threadnameThread.Start();
```

The web cam starts but it never raises ImageCaptured event.

When I run the code under a Dispatcher BeginInvoke, the event gets fired,

```
    System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
                {
//above code
}));
```

But thats not my purpose, because this way the UI slows down. I want to run the webcam in a separate thread, this was my original question

[[Text Input very slow in WPF Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42944161/text-input-very-slow-in-wpf-application][1])

My question is how we can raise a UI event from a background thread.

Thanks.

Comment: Your best chance is to try get access of the code of this WebCamCapture class to find out why it isn't working. I don't see why ImageCapture should only be thrown in the main thread :/

Comment: First, why create a raw trhead in the first place? Why not use `Task.Run()` ? Or use TaskCompletionSource to adapt the events to a task? Second, progress reporting in .NET 4.5+ is performed through `Progress< T>`.

Comment: BTW, using a thread almost *guarantees* that any UI control will fail. You *can't* modify the UI from another thread. If `WebCamCapture` is a control, it will fail if you call it from another thread. `BeginInvoke` marshals the event callback to the UI thread, which is why this works

Comment: Where are you getting that `WebCamCapture` class from? What thread does it raise the event on?